# Task Host is stopping which tasks?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

Occasionally, when I shutdown (or reboot) my computer, I get a message that says

> Task Host is stopping background tasks

I have the choice to "restart anyway" or wait. And if I wait, it eventually times out, and takes me back to my desktop.

Apparently Win 10 apps can have things that run in the background. Is there a way for me to determine what apps are trying to do these things so I can clean up the issue, or uninstall those apps?

---

As a side note (perhaps this should be a separate question?) I don't like this behavior of Windows. Is there any way I can have it restart anyway, or wait longer to actually finish the tasks?

Comment: You can use the `shutdown` command and combine it with `-f` to force the shutdown.

Comment: Oh, good call, although what does `-f` do in this case then? Just kills the apps before they have a chance to shut down? Or does it give them a chance? How long does it give?

Comment: I think they do not get a chance to propper shutdown but they get killed. you can use shutdown together with timers (e.g. wait for 10 sec). you could try to issue two shutdown commands. first one that waits for X seconds and then does `shutdown -f`and another one which does a "normal" shutdown. If the normal shutdown succeeds before X seconds pass: good; if not: forced shutdown